# SQL Azure table size

Tags: azure, size, azure-sql-database

In mssql2005 when I want to get size of table in MBs, I use EXEC sp_spaceused 'table'.

Is there any way to get space used by particular table in SQL Azure using some query or API?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

From Ryan Dunn
http://dunnry.com/blog/CalculatingTheSizeOfYourSQLAzureDatabase.aspx

```sql
select    
      sum(reserved_page_count) * 8.0 / 1024 [SizeInMB]
from    
      sys.dm_db_partition_stats

GO

select    
      sys.objects.name, sum(reserved_page_count) * 8.0 / 1024 [SizeInMB]
from    
      sys.dm_db_partition_stats, sys.objects
where    
      sys.dm_db_partition_stats.object_id = sys.objects.object_id

group by sys.objects.name
order by sum(reserved_page_count) DESC
```

The first one will give you the size of your database in MB and the second one will do the same, but break it out for each object in your database ordered by largest to smallest.

Comment: This gives a significantly smaller size than sp_spaceUsed on SQL Server (e.g. only 40% or so). Is there a reason for this? If you're using an ODBC connection, how can you tell that it's Azure at the back end?

Comment: this would aggregate different tables with identical names, but different schemas, as one, so in case you use logical separation via schemas but use the same tables, this would yield incorrect results.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a query which will give you by table the total size, number of rows and bytes per row:

```
select 
    o.name, 
    max(s.row_count) AS 'Rows',
    sum(s.reserved_page_count) * 8.0 / (1024 * 1024) as 'GB',
    (8 * 1024 * sum(s.reserved_page_count)) / (max(s.row_count)) as 'Bytes/Row'
from sys.dm_db_partition_stats s, sys.objects o
where o.object_id = s.object_id
group by o.name
having max(s.row_count) > 0
order by GB desc
```

And here is a query which is the same as above but breaks it down by index:

```
select  
    o.Name,
    i.Name,
    max(s.row_count) AS 'Rows',
    sum(s.reserved_page_count) * 8.0 / (1024 * 1024) as 'GB',
    (8 * 1024* sum(s.reserved_page_count)) / max(s.row_count) as 'Bytes/Row'
from 
    sys.dm_db_partition_stats s, 
    sys.indexes i, 
    sys.objects o
where 
    s.object_id = i.object_id
    and s.index_id = i.index_id
    and s.index_id >0
    and i.object_id = o.object_id
group by i.Name, o.Name
having SUM(s.row_count) > 0
order by GB desc
```

Answer (score 6):

This way you can have the bigger on top:

```
 SELECT  sys.objects.name,
            SUM(row_count) AS 'Row Count',
            SUM(reserved_page_count) * 8.0 / 1024 AS 'Table Size (MB)'
    FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats, sys.objects
    WHERE sys.dm_db_partition_stats.object_id = sys.objects.object_id
    GROUP BY sys.objects.name
    ORDER BY [Table Size (MB)] DESC
```

[Source](http://blog.clicdata.com/2012/07/31/table-row-count-and-size-in-sql-azure/)

Comment: sum(row_count) is deceptive since it will count 1 row for every row in an index.