# sql azure setting value to null increases table size

Tags: sql-server, database, relational-database, azure-sql-database

I had an uniqueidentifier field in SQL Server (SQL Azure to be precise) that I wanted to get rid of. Initially, when I ran the code as mentioned in [SQL Azure table size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957064/sql-azure-table-size) to determine the size of the table it was about 0.19 MB.

As a first step I set all values in the uniqueidentifier field to null. There are no constraints/indexes that use the column. Now, when I ran the code to determine the table sizes the table had increased in size to about 0.23 MB. There are no records being added to a table (its in a staging environment).

I proceeded to delete the column and it still hovered at the same range. 
Why does the database size show an increase when I delete a column. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting an `uniqueidentifier` column to NULL value does not change the record size in any way, since is a fixed size type (16 bytes). Dropping a fixed size column column does not change the record size, unless is the last column in the physical layout and the space can be reused later. ALTER TABLE ... DROP COLUMN is only a *logical* operation, it simply marks the columns as dropped, see [SQL Server Columns Under the Hood](http://rusanu.com/2011/10/20/sql-server-table-columns-under-the-hood/).

In order to reclaim the space you need to drop the column and then rebuild the clustered index of the table, see [ALTER INDEX ... REBUILD](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188388.aspx).

For the record (since SHRINK is not allowed in SQL Azure anyway) on the standalone SQL Server SHRINK would had solved nothing, this is not about page reservation but about physical record size.

Answer (score 1):

It's counting the number of reserved pages to calculate the size.  Deleting a column may reduce the number of pages that are actually utilized to store data, but the newly-freed pages are probably still reserved for future inserts.

I think you'd need to shrink the database to see the size decrease, as per: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ssdsgetstarted/thread/ae698613-79d5-4f23-88b4-f42ee4b3ad46/

As an aside, I am fairly sure that setting the value of a non-variable-length column (like a GUID) to null will not save you any space at all- only deleting the column will do so.  This per [Space used by nulls in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556363/space-used-by-nulls-in-database)